# Google Checkout Order Report API -> Google Wallet analog?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-checkout, android-pay

I used Google Checkout API for getting subscriptions reports every half an hour. 
https://checkout.google.com/api/checkout/v2/reports/Merchant/
(https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Order_Report_API)

Our company have ours support team which provides help for users of application. My script downloaded last purchases every half an hour and stored in DB (time,serialnumber,email). After that support was getting access to this information through our web-interface (thus, we did not give an access (login,pass) for a main Checkout account).

Now Google Checkout was shut down and I don't understand how to do it at Google Wallet. Does anyone now can it provide this functionality or not?

Comment: Can you pls clarify which API you are (actually) using for subscriptions? Checkout, Wallet for Digital, etc.?

Comment: We WERE using Google Checkout. Now we use Google Wallet (Google forced to do migration by shuting down Checkout)

Comment: Are you selling digital content or physical goods?

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK** there currently is no similar "infrastructure" (reporting, querying, etc, via API like in Google Checkout) for [Google Wallet for Digital Goods](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/index) which, based on your comments, sounds like the product you are looking for (to replace your current Google Checkout implementation) - it's specifically for digital goods and does [support subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions).

You'd [manage orders](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/orders) via Merchant Center.

You will get order data via postbacks so as for ideas - you would need to store order data on your end when you [handle the postback/s from Google](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback) - for both "placed" and "cancelled".

This would replace how you currently do it via Order Report API in Google Checkout...

Hth...